# Not able to get span value in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Hey geeks I am new to selenium and automate testing and I am trying to extract Span values(i.e. l e k C N t in below example) from webpage but either it gives empty value or No such element error. Can anyone help in it!

Language: python

Webpage:

```
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="captcha-letters">
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">l</span>
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">e</span>
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">k</span>
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">C</span>
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">N</span>
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">t</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying that causes that error?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to automate solving a captcha... which was created to stop bots from accessing sites where they aren't welcome. Respect their TOS and don't try to bypass it...

Comment: @JeffC you got me...lol! but I am able to do successful login using selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text from each `span` element element on the page, this should work:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

If you need to be more specific and grab only certain `span` elements, we will need more HTML to go off of.

Comment: Thanks mate it worked!

I did following code:

`contacts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.captcha-letters span')
for contact in contacts:
    print(contact.text)`